# Sending GRPC communications over a specific port

Tags: go, grpc

I am running a GRPC server (Server A) listening on a specific port. I want to be able to send a communication to another server (Server B), and have Server B record the incoming address of Server A's connection so that it may later contact Server A.

On Server A, I listen on a port and create a context like such:

```
lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:6000")
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(),
    10000*time.Millisecond)
```

Then create a connection like so:

```
connection, err = grpc.DialContext(ctx, server2Address,
grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithBlock())
```

Before finally sending a message to an endpoint on Server B, which attempts to read the IP address of Server A's incoming connection

```
info, _ := peer.FromContext(ctx)
fmt.Printf(info.Addr.String()) // Returns a random port, NOT 6000,
```

However, the resulting port printed by Server B is random, like 62056 as opposed to 6000 as intended. My assumption is that, on Server A, GRPC dials from a random port - is it possible to force GRPC to dial from port 6000 as opposed to a random port?

Comment: Why do you care about the client-side's port number?  What is the larger problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Server A knows the address and port of Server B, but not the inverse. Somehow, I need to inform Server B of the address and port of Server A so that Server B may in the future communicate with Server A. So, I am attempting to scrape that information from the context provided by the incoming communication from Server A to Server B, however, the port number is inaccurate, thus this post.

Comment: why not have a gRPC service hosted on serverA on a well known port, so that server B can talk back directly?  Are you trying to do this to handle a particular transaction and need to maintain transaction state? If so, I'd use some token exchange rather than involving some potentially complicated communication pathway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the source port like this:

```
cc, err := grpc.Dial("127.0.0.1:6001", grpc.WithInsecure(),
    grpc.WithContextDialer(func(ctx context.Context, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
        dst, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", addr)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        src := &net.TCPAddr{
            IP:   net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1"),
            Port: 6000,
        }
        return net.DialTCP("tcp", src, dst)
    }))
```

However if your server is listening on the same port this will result in an error:

```
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6000->127.0.0.1:6001: bind: address already in use
```

A different approach would be to pass the address as metadata. On the client you do:

```
ctx := context.Background()
ctx = metadata.NewOutgoingContext(ctx, metadata.Pairs("address", "127.0.0.1:6000"))
res, err := grpc_health_v1.NewHealthClient(cc).Check(ctx, &grpc_health_v1.HealthCheckRequest{
    Service: "test",
})
```

And on the server:

```
func (s *server) Check(ctx context.Context, req *grpc_health_v1.HealthCheckRequest) (*grpc_health_v1.HealthCheckResponse, error) {
    if md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx); ok {
        addr := md.Get("address")
        // addr == "127.0.0.1:6000"
    }

    return &grpc_health_v1.HealthCheckResponse{
        Status: grpc_health_v1.HealthCheckResponse_SERVING,
    }, nil
}
```

And a third approach would be to use [streaming](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CONCEPTS.md#streaming).

Comment: Hello,that's great! But... how do I specify the source port on the java-client channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).build();